# Writing dataframe values to google sheet through gspread_dataframe

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am working in an automation that consists on sending the values of a dataframe to a google sheet, the following is my code for a sample dataframe, which is similar to the one I am working on:

```
#Creates a dictionary containing values for 1 column to be used in pandas dataframe
col =  {'id':["1"],'name':["Juan"], 'code':["1563"], 'group':["3"], 'class':["A"]}

#Creates a pandas dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(col)

df
```

[image]

I need to send to google sheet just the dataframe values, without the header, this is just a sample of the data I am working with, and of course I need the header in the dataframe because I am doing some column transformations in the dataframe before sending it to sheets, due to data comes from an API.

This is the code to send the dataframe to google sheet:

```
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='API_creds.json')
sheet = gc.open_by_key('SHEET_ID')

# Sending values from aimleap dataframe google sheet
row=1
col=1
worksheet = sheet.get_worksheet(0)
set_with_dataframe(worksheet,df,row,col)
```

After sending the dataframe to sheets through `set_with_dataframe(worksheet,df,row,col)`, sheets gets updated with the dataframe including the header, I just need to update the sheet with just the values of the dataframe, how could I modify the parameters of `set_with_dataframe()` to achieve this?

This is how it looks when sending the dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by setting the `include_column_header` argument to False.

```py
set_with_dataframe(worksheet,df,row,col, include_column_header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, norie, it worked, another question so how could add every time I run the script the values of data frame to a new row, means the second time it runs if I send the values to row=1 they will be overwritten. Is there a parameter in set_with_dataframe that I can set so that I can get which is the next empty row in google sheet and then the values will be written in row=?

Comment: Would this be within the same code or when running the code again?

Comment: Within the same code would work or a different chunk of code, I think it would work as well, just give me clue on how could I do it please, thanks!

Comment: The answer really does depend on what you are trying to do, can you give more details?

Comment: Yes of course, so the first day I run the script it will write in the google sheet the line from de dataframe, as I am passing row=1 as a parameter, so how could I do to automate it, so the script knows that the next empty cell is 2 in the google sheet, and that will be the row where the script writes the data, the second day when script executes, other way if writes to row=1 the data will be overwritten, and this is not what I want.

Comment: I have the same question actually. Any insights on how to do this?